# How to access multiple files parallely using Java NIO package?

Tags: java, selector, nio

**Problem Statement :** Develop a standalone application using the java nio package.

**Input :**  1 - String : "searchString" , 2 : String : path of the directory

**Output** : Print the number of count of "searchString" in all files present in the directory.

**Condition :** Read all files in parallel present in given directory.

Comment: Please add some details as to what you have tried, and what in particular is your issue. That will help us answer your problem more effectively.

Comment: This feels a lot like homework, also it sounds like a bad idea performance-wise to be reading files from a single folder in parallel. Unless the only purpose is for homework...

Comment: Define 'in parallel'. Do you mean in separate threads? Or using asynchronous I/O?

Comment: Its kind of assignment and in parallel means using NIO package only with single thread.